# Installing Rails on Mac OS Yosemite v10.10.2 (FNG)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to install Rails onto my Mac and keep running into a this issue. I have no coding/programming experience and am trying to get set up so I can start learning.

I have gone through everything on install rails.com and am not sure what to do.

Your help is appreciated.

make install failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/feferrada/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/feferrada/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out

Answer (score -1):

Follow the steps below to install ruby on rails on mac osx yosemite.

If that does not work please post the exact errors.
For further details about the installation have a look at https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite

### Installing Homebrew

You might be asked to install the XCode CommandLine Tools - say yes.

```
 ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

### Installing Ruby

you can browse the available versions using

```
rbenv install --list
```

installation using homebrew

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build

# Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

# Install Ruby
rbenv install 2.2.1
rbenv global 2.2.1
```

now ruby is installed and you should be able to run

```
ruby -v
# ruby 2.2.1...
```

### Installing Rails

you can browse the available versions of rails using

```
gem list ^rails$ --remove --all
```

installation

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.1
```

to use the rails command run

```
rbenv rehash
```

now rails is installed and you should be able run

```
rails -v
# Rails 4.2.1
```